# How to parse the key value field with Jackson parser android

Tags: android

I am using jackson parser.
What type of field should be created in model class to parse the following field with Object Mapper.

```
directions":
{
 "1":"Heat oil in a nonstick skillet coated with cooking spray over medium heat. Add red bell pepper and garlic; cook, uncovered, 30 minutes, stirring occasionally. Set aside, and cool slightly.",
 "2":"Place pepper mixture in a blender; add chopped basil and next 3 ingredients. Process until smooth, stopping once to scrape down sides.",
 "3":"Cook pasta according to package directions, omitting salt and fat.",
 "4":"To serve, top pasta with pepper sauce. Garnish with basil sprigs, if desired."
}
```

**I have created the field**

```
private HashMap<String,String> directions;
```

But while parsing it is showing an **exception**

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.String]] from String value;
 no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: com.project.android.vo.ModelClass["directions"])
```

Comment: make sure your JSON is correct, post the code where you parsing the JSON. This might be help full http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-json-parsing-made-easy-using-jackson/

Comment: please refer his tapi 
http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html